# ffmpeg Auto Level, Auto Color etc similar to YouTubes Auto-Fix

Tags: ffmpeg

I used to use YouTube Auto-Fix which presumably auto fixed levels, color, contrast and added a bit of vibrance (it was almost always a bit high saturated which i kinda liked).

I am looking for an alternate in ffmpeg. I tried using `-vf pp=al` but it only lightens the video.

Any ideas?

P.S. I can do this in Premiere/AfterEffects but am looking for a ffmpeg solution.

Comment: Look at eq, hue and vibrance filters.

Answer (score 0):

According to this page is not that simple...
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/colorspace

Comment: Welcome! In general, “please see this link” answers are discouraged. Can you summarize the contents of the link in case it becomes unavailable in the future?